# sending push notification using firebase functions every time a new child is added in firebase realtime database is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a push notification every time a child is created with no success.
I am creating a child with 2 token names with a question mark between them and trying to send to those tokens the notification.
to get the tokens from the phones I am using

`new FirebaseMessaging().getToken()` .

here is the firebase functions code 
`

```
// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
exports.onNewMessage = functions.database.
ref('/messages/{pushId}')
.onCreate((snapShot,context)=>{
  var str = snapShot.key();

  var res = str.split("?");

   // Notification details.
   const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: 'title!',
      body: `body!`,
      click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'

    }
  };

  // Send notifications to all tokens.
   admin.messaging().sendToDevice(res[0], payload);
   admin.messaging().sendToDevice(res[1], payload);

});` .
```

Answer (score 1):

This may have many if-thens, but I will describe here the most common sources of errors

**1) Did not grant permissions** for notifications for iOS/Android platform. For Android it is fine, and relatively easy to receive notifications, but for iOS you need Developer account to do that (on December 2019 it was 99$ per year)

**2) I would recommend using topic subscription** instead of tokenization (i.e. *.getToken()*) as it removes burden of following every single sent message manually

For example:

```
final fbmsg = FirebaseMessaging();
fbmsg.requestNotificationPermissions();
fbmsg.configure(onMessage: (msg) {
  print(msg);
  return;
}, onLaunch: (msg) {
  print(msg);
  return;
}, onResume: (msg) {
  print(msg);
  return;
});

fbmsg.subscribeToTopic('chats');
```

You can configure onLaunch, onResume, and onMessage behaviors on your own demand

For (1) and (2), a great place to start is following [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#-readme-tab-) of *firebase_messaging* library

**3)** I am not sure about this, but I think a better way to use `index.js` file could be using the snapshot that you receive (or at least try console.log() of whatever you get to check validity). But if it works for you, just ignore this step :) Below I attach the code from my app with working notifications

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('chats/{message}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic('chats', {
        notification: {
            title: snapshot.data().username,
            body: snapshot.data().text,
            clickAction: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
        },
    });
  });
```

**4)** I had hard time with establishing this Firebase Functions feature, also check installation steps for them as well

**5)** Check how you are trying to send the notification, first try to simulate it from the console, make sure that receiving part works, and then try to create an automated one

Hope it helped!